# Is there any reason to use the HTTP 410 GONE status code?

Tags: http

When permanently removing a page from your website,
are there any practical benefits to setting up a `410 GONE` HTTP response for the URL?
(vs. letting it `404 NOT FOUND`)

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the `410 Gone` HTTP status code conveys that the resource requested was once available in the past, but it has now been retired or made obsolete.

The `404 Not Found` HTTP status code could imply that the website has been incorrectly updated so as to be missing a file that would normally be defined there. It could also mean that the requesting client referenced a resource that never did exist and probably never will.

The `410 Gone` status can have more immediate SEO implications because it tells search engines that the missing resource was intentionally removed. That should hasten the reduction of future search references to that page more so than the `404 Not Found` status.

Comment: "can have more immediate SEO implications". That would indeed be nice. Do we know if any search engines actually make this distinction?

Comment: The search engine firms don't divulge all details of their algorithms for competitive reasons. However, it is in their interests to make this distinction.

Answer (score 3):

I could imagine if you have a public API, and you finally disable your long deprecated v1 after publishing like v4 or something, you could use this statuscode to make it obvious to consumers of that API. But then again one could argue that a 301 is also valid for this type of situation. It also depends on how different it is, and whether there is an actual replacement, or is it just actually gone.

From [RFC 9110](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-410-gone):

> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that remote links to that resource be removed. Such an event is common for limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to individuals no longer working at the server's site. It is not necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as "gone" or to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to the discretion of the server owner.