# How can an ICS/VCALENDAR file be marked as end of life / no longer synced?

Tags: php, calendar, synchronization, icalendar, vcalendar

I set up a calendar for sports fixtures at a major competition. The competition has now ended but I'm still getting gigabytes of bandwidth usage every month (presumably from the calendar syncing for those that added it to Google Calendar etc).

Is it possible to set an end date for any updates, or somehow disable syncing? I'd rather not just torpedo the file, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like any other page that you getting too much unwanted traffic or that is no longer available.   Use the http status codes https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Maybe 410 Gone? 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/410 
See [Is there any reason to use the HTTP 410 GONE status code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39855536/is-there-any-reason-to-use-the-http-410-gone-status-code)

Alternatively if you still want some to have access to historical data,  block the unwanted traffic via htaccess, just like one blocks, spiders, crawlers, bots

Comment: Good shout on the status codes, thanks! I had assumed there was a way to set and "end date" for syncing a calendar within the markup.