# iCalendar (.ics) feed, how to force calendar client to stop the subscription

Tags: icalendar

I have an online service where it lets people subscribe to iCalendar feed.
I'm wondering if there is a way to force the subscriber (their Calendar client) to stop their subscription.
I have one subscriber who is subscribed to a feed that doesn't exist anymore. The annoying part is that this subscriber is fetching the data every 4 seconds!

I looked at iCalendar specification and it doesn't look like this is supported.

I tried few http response codes (404 and 410), but this doesn't stop the client.

The user agent I'm seeing in the log shows "iOS/12.5.4 (16H50) dataaccessd/1.0".

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is similar to a 'broken' link that keeps trying to fetch a page that no longer exists.  [How to unpublish an iCal (*.ics) feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099117/how-to-unpublish-an-ical-ics-feed?rq=1)

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't answer the issue as over there they also currently indicates that even when changing to 410 as listed above in the question they still keep on getting the request.